# use sed and grep to find title in file1 and move the content to file2 with same title

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

i have file1 and file2

```
FILE1 :
title1 linkabc
title2 linkdef
title3 linkfgh
title4 linkdse
title5 linklsfr
title6 linkfhghg
title7 linksdrlk
title8 linklklghkj
title9 linkghftht
```

and in FILE2

```
FILE2 :
title1
anothertitle2
title3
anothertitle4
title5
anothertitle6
title7
anothertitle8
title9
```

as you can see in file2 there are no links only the title match , 
and i want to make the output like below

```
OUTPUT :
title1 linkabc
anothertitle2
title3 linkfgh
anothertitle4
title5 linklsfr
anothertitle6
title7 linksdrlk
anothertitle8
title9 linkghftht
```

As you can see if file1 and file2 title doesnt match leave as it is

i can pull the link with this command

```
cat FILE1 | grep "title1" | grep -oh link.*
```

i just cant figure out how to append output link to FILE2 .

after search test and failed again and again , i gave up , hope someone can help me solve this.

thank you!

*sorry edited my question was not clear im too confused already , my bad.

Comment: extending your command `cat FILE1 | grep "title1" | grep -oh link.* | xargs -i sed -i -e 's/title1/title1 {}/g' FILE2`

Comment: you can read each line of file1, and then grep file2: `cat file2.txt | while read -r LINE; do grep "^$LINE " file1.txt; done`

Comment: sorry guys my bad , i've edited my post .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, but a simple approach would be to take every line of `FILE2` and then `grep` for this in `FILE1`.

```
while read -r LINE; do if ! grep "^$LINE " FILE1; then echo $LINE; fi; done < FILE2
```

Or if you prefer, you can cat the file first:

```
cat FILE2 | while read -r LINE; do if ! grep "^$LINE " FILE1; then echo $LINE; fi; done
```

This will then just echo the LINE it's reading from FILE2 if there's no match in FILE1.

Example proof:

```
rseaman@Ubuntu-PC:~/temp$ cat FILE1
title1 linkabc
title2 linkdef
title3 linkfgh
title4 linkdse
title5 linklsfr
title6 linkfhghg
title7 linksdrlk
title8 linklklghkj
title9 linkghftht
rseaman@Ubuntu-PC:~/temp$ cat FILE2
title1
anothertitle2
title3
anothertitle4
title5
anothertitle6
title7
anothertitle8
title9
rseaman@Ubuntu-PC:~/temp$ while read -r LINE; do if ! grep "^$LINE " FILE1; then echo $LINE; fi; done < FILE2
title1 linkabc
anothertitle2
title3 linkfgh
anothertitle4
title5 linklsfr
anothertitle6
title7 linksdrlk
anothertitle8
title9 linkghftht
```

Comment: `while ... do ... done < FILE2` is better than `cat FILE2 | while ...`.

Comment: I agree - I have modified my answer.

Comment: I've modified my answer to work with your new requirements.

Comment: sir , i prefer this method     cat file2.txt | while read -r LINE; do grep "^$LINE " file1.txt; done , but can i keep title that doesnt has any link ?

i use you method while read -r LINE it agve me lots of blank space

Comment: I've added the proof of this working to my answer, and I've added the alternative using `cat` initially. What issues are you having? Your latest comment wasn't very clear.

Comment: nice . i accepted this answer , i must remove special char first on my FILE and use your method . thank you Robert

Comment: That's extremely slow and buggy. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and then see [@karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618399/1745001) for how to really do this task in a UNIX environment.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1, a[$1]}' file1 file2


title1 linkabc
anothertitle2
title3 linkfgh
anothertitle4
title5 linklsfr
anothertitle6
title7 linksdrlk
anothertitle8
title9 linkghftht
```

Comment: very elegant :)

Comment: Very nice. I've just learned another thing about `awk` today.

Answer (score 0):

## Updating answer because you updated the question

```
(grep -F -w -f file2 file1) && (grep -v -F -w -f <(cut -d' ' -f1 file1) file2)
```

will do what you seek, however it scrambles the input order. At this stage it probably makes sense to go with a more granular solution

```
bash-3.00$ (grep -F -w -f file2 file1) && (grep -v -F -w -f <(cut -d' ' -f1 file1) file2)
title1 linkabc
title3 linkfgh
title5 linklsfr
title7 linksdrlk
title9 linkghftht
anothertitle2
anothertitle4
anothertitle6
anothertitle8
```

---

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

This will perform a partial match taking the input from file 2

Here are the results

```
bash-3.00$ cat file1
title1 linkabc
title2 linkdef
title3 linkfgh
title4 linkdse
title5 linklsfr
title6 linkfhghg
title7 linksdrlk
title8 linklklghkj
title9 linkghftht
bash-3.00$ cat file2
title1
title3
title5
title7
title9
bash-3.00$ grep -f file2 file1
title1 linkabc
title3 linkfgh
title5 linklsfr
title7 linksdrlk
title9 linkghftht
bash-3.00$
```

Addressing Robert's query, if that were the case i would do
`grep -F -w -f file2 file1`

```
bash-3.00$ cat file1
title1 linkabc
title2 linkdef
title3 linkfgh
title4 linkdse
title5 linklsfr
title6 linkfhghg
title7 linksdrlk
title8 linklklghkj
title9 linkghftht
title10 linkxyxyz
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$ cat file2
title1
title3
title5
title7
title9
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$ grep -F -w -f file2 file1
title1 linkabc
title3 linkfgh
title5 linklsfr
title7 linksdrlk
title9 linkghftht
bash-3.00$
```

Comment: What if you have 10+ titles?

Comment: Nice catch Robert, I've addressed it :)

Comment: As long as the title key is unique then I prefer this approach. Obviously it doesn't edit the file inplace so you can output this to another file if that's a requirement.

Comment: this worked man , but the only problem is for that doesnt match were erase ,

Comment: could you elaborate please ?

Answer (score 0):

After the update of the question You can try with gnu join :

```
join --nocheck-order -a 2 FILE1 FILE2
```

If you want to update FILE2

```
printf "$(join --nocheck-order -a 2 FILE1 FILE2)" >FILE2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#\(.*\) .*#s/^\1$/&/#' file1 | sed -f - file2
```

Turn file1 into a sed script and run it against file2.

The script matches the key in file2 and replaces that line with the contents of the matching line from file1.

Comment: i got this error sed: file - line 1: unknown option to `s' perhaps due spesial character on my files

Comment: @DRMTV if the input file may contain metadata characters, first convert these to quoted characters using `s/[]()^$&.?+\[/]/\\&/g`